# Resume thread and work on another button in the meantime

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new in C#. I found some code which work on progressbar. What is does, when someone click on button start `btnStartAsyncOperation_Click` the progress bar starts increasing and when `btnCancel_Click` is pressed it cancel the operation. Here is the code

```
namespace BackgroundWorkerSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {       
        BackgroundWorker m_oWorker;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
            m_oWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            m_oWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(m_oWorker_DoWork);
            m_oWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(m_oWorker_ProgressChanged);
            m_oWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(abcd);
            m_oWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            m_oWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        void abcd(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {           
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Cancelled.";
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Error while performing background operation.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Task Completed...";
            }
            btnStartAsyncOperation.Enabled = true;
            btnCancel.Enabled = false;
        }

        void m_oWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lblStatus.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }

        void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                m_oWorker.ReportProgress(i);
                if (m_oWorker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    m_oWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                    return;

                }

            }

            //Report 100% completion on operation completed
            m_oWorker.ReportProgress(100);
        }

        private void btnStartAsyncOperation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStartAsyncOperation.Enabled  = false;
            btnCancel.Enabled               = true;
            //Start the async operation here

            m_oWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (m_oWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                //Stop/Cancel the async operation here
                m_oWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void lblStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        }
    }
```

Now I added 2 more button, button1 to pause and button2 to resume. Since I could not find any method to resume, I had to use `CancelAsync()` function when I press pause and I keep the value of progress bar in a global variable. Then when I press resume I start the progress bar again using `RunWorkerAsync`. But the problem is, I can not send the value of global variable in this function so it start from 0 progress.

I tried to use `thread.sleep(infinite time here)` when someone press pause and then stop the thread when someone press resume. Still the problem is, I can not press any button in this situation. Still if I enable button they don't work.

Please give me some solution.

Comment: You should probably look up async/await or Reactive Extensions. Pretty much designed for these types of problems.

Comment: @MeirionHughes could you please give me some links

Answer (score 0):

You could try having your own variable, i.e

```
bool isPaused = false;
```

When someone clicks your pause button...

```
isPaused = true;
```

And set it to false when someone clicks resume. Finally, in your for loop in your doWork method, make it wait until that variable is false.

```
while (isPaused) 
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Let me know how this works out for you.